# UICollectionView dynamically resize height to display all content without scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to dynamically resize UICollectionView height and display all cells without scrolling when page loads.

I tried following codes in viewDidLoad but didn't work

```
self.constraintTableViewHeight.constant = self.myProfileCollectionView.contentSize.height
```

or

```
self.constraintTableViewHeight.constant = self.myProfileCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize().height
```

Comment: Hi If you have got solution , then please tell me

Answer (score 4):

call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

after

```
self.constraintTableViewHeight.constant = self.myProfileCollectionView.contentSize.height
```

If it will not help try to move this code to view `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: I tried both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear but it still display within its height constraint and keep scrolling.